# SELECT COUNT INTO variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get the row count of a table and store it in a variable so I can use that variable however it will only store it in the variable if I use 
`WHERE ROWNUM = 1;` but then it only stores the number 1 rather than the actual number of rows.
The whole select statement I'm using is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO vn_no_tickets
FROM tickets
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

If I don't use `WHERE ROWNUM = 1;` I get an error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows", but again when I do use it, I get just 1 row not the actual number or rows.
Thanks

Edit: Here is the full procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_ticket_exp IS
    vn_no_tickets NUMBER(4);
    vn_ticket_id tickets.ticket_id%TYPE;
    vd_exp_date tickets.expiration_date%TYPE;
    vc_customer_firstname tickets.customer_firstname%TYPE;
    vc_customer_surname tickets.customer_surname%TYPE;
    vd_one_week DATE;
    vc_fullname VARCHAR2(40); 
BEGIN
    vd_one_week := sysdate + 7;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO vn_no_tickets
    FROM tickets
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (vn_no_tickets);

    WHILE vn_no_tickets != 0 LOOP
        SELECT expiration_date, ticket_id, customer_firstname, customer_surname
        INTO vd_exp_date, vn_ticket_id, vc_customer_firstname,  vc_customer_surname
        FROM tickets
        WHERE ROWNUM = vn_no_tickets;
        vc_fullname := CONCAT(vc_customer_firstname, CONCAT(' ', vc_customer_surname));
        IF vd_exp_date < vd_one_week THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (vc_fullname || 's ticket will expire within one week. Ticket Number: ' || vn_ticket_id);
        END IF;
        vn_no_tickets := vn_no_tickets - 1;
    END LOOP;        
END proc_ticket_exp;
/ 
SHOW ERRORS
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` without `GROUP BY`  would return single scaler value.

Comment: Not exactly. `select count(*) into vn_no_tickets from tickets;` (without the `rownum` condition) *will* select actual number of rows from the `tickets` table. It means that there's some more code (you didn't post) which raises the `too_many_rows` error.

Comment: @Littlefoot what else could be causing that error? This is pretty much the only code which deals with the count and vn_no_tickets

Comment: *Something* else. I can't guess without seeing code you wrote.

Comment: I've just edited the post with the full procedure if that helps

Comment: is the condition  WHERE ROWNUM <= vn_no_tickets; or  WHERE ROWNUM = vn_no_tickets;

Answer (score 2):

Your actual code which is failing is the below since in first query you put `rownum=1` you will get `count also as 1` hence `vn_no_tickets will be 1`.If you remove the `rownum=1` in first query then `vn_no_tickets will be greater than 1` and the below query will `fail`

```
    SELECT expiration_date, ticket_id, customer_firstname, customer_surname
    INTO vd_exp_date, vn_ticket_id, vc_customer_firstname,  vc_customer_surname
    FROM tickets
    WHERE ROWNUM <= vn_no_tickets;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) on `ROWNUM` is quite explicit:

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:
>
> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM employees
> WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
> ```
>
> The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned.

(Note:  This also applies to an equality comparison higher than 1.)

So, this condition:

```
    WHERE ROWNUM = vn_no_tickets
```

only returns a row when `vn_no_tickets` is "1".

The simplest way to fix this is to dispense with the counter:

```
FOR t IN (SELECT expiration_date, ticket_id, customer_firstname, customer_surname
         FROM tickets
         )
LOOP
    vc_fullname := t.customer_firstname || ' ' || t.customer_surname;
    IF t.exp_date < vd_one_week THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (vc_fullname || 's ticket will expire within one week. Ticket Number: ' || t.ticket_id);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

That said, you should move the `IF` condition into the `WHERE` clause.  It is silly to retrieve a row from the database, just to check a condition -- when that condition can be used to filter the result set in the first place.